# Polarity symbols on universal AC-DC adaptor

Tags: power-supply, converter, adapter, symbol, polarity

I have a universal AC-DC adaptor that has the following symbol by the polarity switch:

[image]

Is it safe to assume that the top part of the diagram indicates the polarity of the inner surface of the cylinder, and the bottom part indicates the polarity of the outer surface?

I'd like to know which way I should push the switch to match the required positive polarity on my 12V DC device:

[image]

Comment: That's a pretty bad diagram.  Personally, I'd use a multimeter to measure the voltage at the connector and find out.  Be sure to mark up the switch positions so that you know what's what the next time you need to look at that particular unit.

Comment: duplicate and answer here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/311714/rca-ah5-ac-dc-adapter-switch-polarity-question

Answer (score 2):

Assume Nothing, Verify Everything.
1 - The center conductor should be Pos.
2 - It sure looks like an improper symbol is being used on the CB.
3 - If the switch is to the LEFT then the circuit is POS to the Top and Neg to the Bottom.
4 - If the switch is to the Right then the circuit is NEG to the Top and POS to the Bottom.  - Simple answer - The + & - are correct it is the Battery Pictorial that is incorrect.
5 - My SWAG is since the symbol is so poor it confused the board manufacture and he just got sloppy.