# RCA AH5 AC/DC adapter switch polarity question

Tags: power-supply

I apologize in advance for asking this, as this *should* be answered via Google search but I'm not finding the correct manual for the RCA AH5 power adapter. And before I fry anymore instruments by using the wrong polarity (which I've done twice before) I'll risk the embarrassment.

I have a RCA AH5 AC/DC adapter. I need to know for sure which switch is for negative polarity. The manuals online show an "adapter receptacle" and the tip. I am familiar with those. This adapter have a switch, no "adapter receptacle" or a tip that you align it up with.

Isn't the negative polarity with the switch down in this photo? If you can't make it out, it shows a (-) at the tip, and a (+) at the base of the tip. I assume that's it but I'm not taking another chance and going to ask here.

It's a crappy iPhone photo but that's the only camera I have at the moment.

Thanks in advance...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. The switch position shown has negative at tip of jack and positive on the sleeve. Most devices would use positive at jack.

Note that you have it on 12 V setting and this could be frying your devices even at the right polarity. Furthermore, there may be very poor voltage regulation in the device so that the 12 V becomes 16 V if lightly loaded. I would only use this for non-electronic devices such as devices with motors or lamps. For anything electronic I would use a regulated power supply.

Standardise all your connectors to "tip +" if you can for safety.

Nice tablecloth!

Comment: Hmm, this is for a synthesizer module, specifically a Kawai K4r. I also have another power supply that was used for my Tascam Porta02 4 track cassette player. I wonder how I find out if i'ts a regulated power supply. I didn't realize this so I really should be using regulate power supplies with my instruments I bet. Thanks!

Comment: They sound too expensive to risk their lives on a very cheap power supply. What do the nameplates or manuals on the instruments say for input power? Both of those units will have internal voltage regulators both for safety (in case someone plugs in a cheap power supply - cough, cough) and to regulate the voltage close to the circuitry that requires it. It doesn't hurt to regulate at the wall wart but it may be overkill. I have a guitar effects unit that takes 12 V AC. Since it's rectified internally it can take a DC of either polarity.

Comment: Great info! LOL, you are probably right about risking it's life on a cheap power supply. The name plate says DC 12V (negative polarity). I am going to look up the manual now and double-check all of this. I just got this in a trade for my drum machine. Now that I think about it, the guy handed me another adapter, which I haven't looked at yet and it's 12V positive polarity power supply, I guess he was using it on on this!!! OMG, even I know that's not good. Hopefully it works but I'm going to research before I plug it in. Thanks, going to look up the manual.

Answer (score 1):

The labelling indicates that with the switch down, the tip of the output plug will be negative.

If you have any doubt, you can easily check this with a voltmeter (DVM, multimeter).

Comment: Ok. I do have a voltmeter here at the house. I've never used it before but maybe I should try. I'll look into how to check this with a voltmeter online, Google should easily give  me a good  answer I would think. Thank you!